# Error trying to save changes when property is also part of the foreign key using Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table [dbo].[Feature]

```
public class Feature
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public ICollection<FeatureProperty> FeatureProperties { get; set; } = new List<FeatureProperty>();

    public ICollection<ProductFeature> ProductFeatures { get; set; } = new List<ProductFeature>();

    internal class FeatureConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Feature>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Feature> builder)
        {
            builder.HasMany(c => c.FeatureProperties)
                   .WithOne(c => c.Feature)
                   .HasForeignKey(c => c.FeatureId)
                   .IsRequired()
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.HasKey(c => c.Id)                
                .IsClustered(true);

            builder.Property(c => c.Id)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
            
            builder.Property(c => c.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            builder.HasIndex(c => c.Name)           
                .IsUnique();            
        }            
    }    
}
```

I have a table [dbo].[Property]

```
public class Property
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    internal class PropertyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Property>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Property> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(c => c.Id)
                .IsClustered(true);

            builder.Property(c => c.Id)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");

            builder.Property(c => c.Name)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            builder.HasIndex(c => new { c.Name })
                .IsUnique();
        }
    }
}
```

We have a many to many table [dbo].[FeatureProperty] that relates features with properties.

```
public class FeatureProperty
{
    public Guid FeatureId { get; set; }

    public Feature? Feature { get; set; }

    public Guid PropertyId { get; set; }

    public Property? Property { get; set; }

    public string? Value { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductFeatureProperty> ProductFeatureProperties { get; set; } = new List<ProductFeatureProperty>();

    internal class DeviceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<FeatureProperty>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FeatureProperty> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(c => new { c.FeatureId, c.PropertyId })
                .IsClustered(true);

            builder.Property(c => c.Value)
                .HasMaxLength(50);
        }
    }    
}
```

We also have a table [dbo].[Product]

```
public class Product
{   
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductFeature> ProductFeatures { get; set; } = new List<ProductFeature>();  
    
    internal class DeviceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(c => c.Id)
                .IsClustered(true);

            builder.Property(c => c.Id)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");

            builder.Property(c => c.Name)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasMaxLength(255);
            
            builder.Property(c => c.Active)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasDefaultValue(true);

            builder.HasIndex(c => new { c.Name })
                .IsUnique();
        }
    }
    
}
```

We have a many to many table [dbo].[ProductFeature] that relates products with features.

```
public class ProductFeature
{
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public Product? Product { get; set; }

    public Guid FeatureId { get; set; }

    public Feature? Feature { get; set; }

    internal class ProductFeatureConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProductFeature>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductFeature> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(c => new { c.ProductId, c.FeatureId })
                .IsClustered(true);

            builder.Property(c => c.ProductId)
                .IsRequired(true);

            builder.Property(c => c.FeatureId)
                .IsRequired(true);

            builder.HasOne(bc => bc.Product)
                .WithMany(b => b.ProductFeatures)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ProductId);

            builder.HasOne(bc => bc.Feature)
                .WithMany(b => b.ProductFeatures)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.FeatureId);
        }
    }
}
```

To explain all this classes. We have a product. A product can have features and features can have properties with a default value. First we relate features and properties using table [dbo].[FeatureProperty], then we relate products with features using the table [dbo].[ProductFeatures]. This help us to get all properties related to the feature associated with the product. We get the FeatureId associated with the product and then get all properties in [dbo].[FeatureProperty].

Now, the team wants to introduce another table which allow us to override the default value of the property per specific product, so we introduced a new table called [dbo].[ProductFeatureProperties]. For example product A have a feature F with a property Size with a default value of 50. Now product B also have a feature F but instead wants to override the value of the property Size to 100

```
public class ProductFeatureProperty
{
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public Product? Product { get; set; }

    public Guid FeatureId { get; set; }

    public Feature? Feature { get; set; }

    public Guid PropertyId { get; set; }

    public Property? Property { get; set; }

    public string? Value { get; set; }

    public ProductFeature? ProductFeature { get; set; }

    public FeatureProperty FeatureProperty { get; set; } = new FeatureProperty();


    internal class ProductFeaturePropertyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProductFeatureProperty>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductFeatureProperty> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(c => new { c.ProductId, c.FeatureId, c.PropertyId })
                .IsClustered(true);

            builder.Property(c => c.Value)
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            builder.Property(c => c.ETag)
                .IsRowVersion();

            builder.HasOne(c => c.FeatureProperty)
                .WithMany(c => c.ProductFeatureProperties)
                .HasForeignKey(c => new { c.FeatureId, c.PropertyId })
                .HasPrincipalKey(c => new { c.FeatureId, c.PropertyId });
        }
    }
}
```

We were struggling with this new table to make navigation works when the product wants to override a default property value. We make it work using `HasForeignKey` and `HasPrincipalKey`.

Now we are trying to build some unit test to insert data on `[dbo].[ProductFeatureProperty]` and we are getting this error:

> The value of 'FeatureProperty.FeatureId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known

We tried many things, I'm sure there is something related on this new table which has PK and FK at the same time, also we believe that this new table with PK Product+Feature+Property, have FK first with Product+Feature (in `[dbo].[ProductFeature]` table) and then with Feature+Property (in `[dbo].[FeatureProperty]` table)

We are using EF6 with SQL Server 2019.

Any help will be really appreciated :), sorry for the long post

Comment: One thing, when it comes to singular navigation properties, don't auto-initialize them:
'public FeatureProperty FeatureProperty { get; set; } /* don't = new FeatureProperty(); */` Only collections should be initialized. If your test didn't happen to set this FeatureProperty up correctly this would hide the cause and result in an error like what you;re seeing as it tries to associate a FeatureProperty with a FeatureId of Guid.Empty.

Comment: You are absolutely right! that fix the problem. Thank you so much Steve!